# Encryption of NTDS.dit (BOOTKEY)

Tags: windows, active-directory

Looking around I found some information regarding NTDS.dit encryption and I wanted to learn a little bit more around the BOOTKEY and whether this is rotated each boot up sequence or is just held static? Or is it changed every 30 days or so?

If a Domain Controller were to completly fail then I would also assume that you would need a full machine restore since the PEK key is encrypted with a unique BOOTKEY as per each domain controller? Below is information I found from [Microsoft Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/924019ab-8497-4fb7-977f-26f184723980/a-question-about-ad-password-storage-and-encryption?forum=winserverDS):

> The PEK or Password Encryption Key is used to encrypt data stored in
> NTDS.DIT. This key is the same across the whole domain, which means
> that it is the same on all the domain controllers.

> The PEK itself is also stored in the NTDS.DIT in an encrypted form. The PEK is encrypted with the BOOTKEY which is different on all
> domain controllers (and in fact on all computers in the domain).

> The SYSKEY are used to drive the PEK (Password Encryption Key) that in its turn are used to encrypt sensitive information inside the
> Active Directory database (NTDS.dit) – Not the entire DB is protected
> by the PEK on certain information such as Password Hashes etc.

Comment: So, your question boils down to "what is a Windows bootkey?" Once you know that, then the rest of your questions answer themselves. And that means this is purely a Windows internals question, not a security question. And once you refine your question to that, you have a very simple google search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/syskey-exe-utility-is-no-longer-supported